# SDL2 Not destroying textures properly when updating text

Tags: sdl2, c

Im implementing a series of textboxes in sdl2 ,however my program is not working correctly
-sdl is not destroying textures when the destroytexture function is callled resulting in a weird overlap of new text and old text that hasnt been destroyed at all.

```
                SDL_Texture *tempBox = textBox(buffer[Z], font, color, renderer, 200);
                renderTexture(tempBox, renderer, cooridnates[Z][0], cooridnates[Z][1], NULL);
                SDL_DestroyTexture(tempBox);

                if (boxState[Z] == 1)
                {
                    if (buttonPress.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT || buttonPress.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                    {
                        if (buttonPress.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && buttonPress.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_BACKSPACE && strlen(buffer[Z]) > 1)
                        {
                            buffer[Z][strlen(buffer[Z]) - 1] = '\0';
                        }

                        if (buttonPress.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT)
                        {
                            strcat(buffer[Z], buttonPress.text.text);
                        }

                        if (buttonPress.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RETURN)
                        {
                            strcat(buffer[Z], "\n ");
                        }
                    }            
                }
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

in the first textbox , text is being created properly as per the code segment , however the second textbox demonstrates what happens when I press backspace and try to add new text , the old text simply remains despite the fact that SDL_Destroytexture is being called.

The code segment is of course in a game loop and is being called again and again.

[image]

Comment: Are you clearing the destination buffer in between disposing of the old text and drawing the new text?

Comment: @DMGregory its a textbox so I would not want to get rid of all the contents in the destination buffer before rendering .

Comment: What I mean is, what are you doing to erase the old text before drawing new text?

Comment: @DMGregory   buffer[Z][strlen(buffer[Z]) - 1] = '\0';

Comment: That does not erase the pixels from the texture you've blitted the previous text into.

Comment: @DMGregory  okay , what woul the appropriate thing to do be?